# simply connectedness implies unbounded connected components?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

Let $\Omega:=\{z\in\Bbb{C};\;0<\Im(z)<1\},$ it's convex so simply connected.

As we can see the two connected components of $\Bbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ are not bounded.

Any exemple I can imagine of open connected sets of $\Bbb{C}$ that are simply connected have this property. So I imagine the following result is true:

> Let $\Omega$ an open connected set of $\Bbb{C}.$ If $\Omega$ is simply connected then the c of $\Bbb{C}\setminus\Omega$ are not bounded.

I am aware that a proof use, probably, algebraic topology. It's not a problem to read but much harder to find, I think.

Is the result true? If yes, where I can find a proof?(even in the form of exercise)

Comment: You can show this slightly indirectly: a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is simply connected iff the complement (in the Riemann sphere) is connected.  If the complement didn't have an unbounded component, then the point at infinity of the Riemann sphere would be isolated, and that only makes sense if your open set is all of $\mathbb{C}$. For a proof of the equivalence, see theorem 11.0 in Ullrich's *Complex Made Simple* (I'm sure there are other sources too).